# Ошибка Ansible: "ERROR! 'mysql_user' is not a valid attribute for a Play"

Tags: mysql, python, linux, ansible, yaml

Хост машина с Ansible 2.3.1.0 - Ubuntu 17.04, клиентская нода - Centos 7(LXC). 
Побродив в гугле на гитхабе в поисках проблемы, опробовал несколько вариантов решения проблемы: установки пакетов MySQL-python,python-mysqldb и прочие, в т.ч и для версии 3.4. Что странно, так это то, что через плейбук я смог выполнить mysql_secure_installation пошагово, а простого пользователя добавить не могу, когда казалось бы через ту же либо mysql-python будет работать.
При выполнении плейбука вида:

```
---
- hosts: lxc01
 become: yes
 tasks:
 name: add mysql user
 mysql_user:
 name: bob
 password: 12345
 priv: '*.*:ALL, GRANT'
```

Получаю:

```
ERROR! 'mysql_user' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to have been in '/home/sat/jedi/mysq.yml': line 2, 
column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- hosts: trapeznikov-lxc01
  ^ here
```

библиотеки требуемые для выполнения этой операции, указанные в офф документации Ansible установлены, дальше даже пробовал модули через pip устанавливать и на хосте и на клиенте, все равно 0 толку.
Может проще кормить в импорт .sql файлы с запросами?
Кто подскажет, что не так делаю?

Comment: Спасибо, подвинул вроде зашло, просто почему Ansible ругается на mysql_user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, что вы не понимаете синтаксис yaml?

Предполагаю, что вы хотели написать что-то типа:

```
---

- name: add mysql users
  hosts: lxc01
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: add mysql user1
      mysql_user:
        name: bob1
        password: 12345
        priv: '*.*:ALL, GRANT'
    - name: add mysql user2
      mysql_user:
        name: bob2
        password: 12345
        priv: '*.*:ALL, GRANT'
```

Простой пример в документации можно посмотреть здесь:

- [Playbook Language Example](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_intro.html#playbook-language-example)

Comment: может все таки YAML?

Comment: Вот не знаю не знаю насчет синтаксиса, кластер же я смог поднять через ansible в galera master-master и балансировку залепить, а проблема только с mysq_user зашла, вот и запутался:)